# How do I get Lost Maiamai off walls?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

At Lake Hylia, there's a suspicious looking place on a wall, with a sign warning against bombing the wall, because of an odd creature living in the cave hidden within.

After renting bombs from the bunny merchant hogging my home, I proceeded to bomb the wall (I'm not good with rules and advices, I know) and went to explore the cave. Inside I found Mother Maiamai who told me this heartbreaking story about how she lost her many little Maiamai and asked me to help find them. I agreed to help, naturally.

After exiting the cave, I found one of the Lost Maiamai stuck on the very same wall I had bombed earlier and wanted to pick it up, but it's stuck on the wall. I can't pick it up, even though I have those awesome Power Gauntlets. Also, none of my current items helped (it's amazing how resilient those little creatures are, even against bombs)

So I was wondering, if I'd need to find a more powerful alternative to the Power Gauntlets, in order to pick the Lost Maiamai off the wall, or if there is another way I haven't thought of yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may not be apparent at first glance, but there actually is a way to pick the Maiamai off the wall without having to progress any further.

Just merge with the wall, then move right under the Maiamai and unmerge. By unmerging, you will easily detach the Maiamai from the wall.

I just hope Mother Maiamai won't mind the rough handling.

Answer (score 5):

Got stuck with this as well, Go to the wall, go right under Maimai and back away, this **should** detach Maimai. Hope this helped